# How to display images on PHP page from my database?

Tags: php, database, image, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to display images and relevant data based on what the user enters in a form(IMG 1). Everything is working but I need the table to show the actual image instead of URL.

In my database, I've got the image data stored as URL but I want to show as an image on the PHP page (IMG 3).

[IMG - 1: What User Enters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rPuV.png)

[image]

[IMG - 2: Result of Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weuOx.png)
[image]

[IMG - 3: Set up on phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v64Dc.png)
[image]

So in the table (IMG 2), I want the actual image to show up instead of link

Here is the most important part of the code that does the searching and displays the data.

```
    $title = trim($_POST["PhotoTitle"]);
    $FromDate = trim($_POST["FromDate"]);
    $ToDate = trim($_POST["ToDate"]);
    $keywords = trim($_POST["keywords"]);

    $query ="SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE `Photo-Title` like '%".$title."%' AND `Keywords` like '%".$keywords."%' AND `Date-of-Photo` BETWEEN '$FromDate' AND '$ToDate'";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>\n ";
        echo "<td>",$row["Photo-Title"],"</td>\n";
        echo "<td>",$row["Description"],"</td>\n";
        echo "<td>",$row["Date-of-Photo"],"</td>\n";
        echo "<td>",$row["Keywords"],"</td>\n";
        echo "<td>",$row["Reference-to-S3"],"</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n ";
    }
```

I can provide any other information if needed.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want the s3 url to be visible to the outside world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit your while to this piece of code :

```php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>\n ";
        echo "<td>",$row["Photo-Title"],"</td>\n";
        echo "<td>",$row["Description"],"</td>\n";
        echo "<td>",$row["Date-of-Photo"],"</td>\n";
        echo "<td>",$row["Keywords"],"</td>\n";
        echo "<td><img src='" . $row["Reference-to-S3"] . "' alt='" . $row["Photo-Title"] . "' /></td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n ";
    }
```

what it does is displaying a URL as an image using `<img />` tag of HTML. Also, `alt` adds a title to the image which if you hover image, you can see the value of this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

First: Your code is highly insecure. It is vulnerable to sql injections and XSS.

Regarding your Question: You need to output an  html tag with the image url as the src attribute.

Like this:

```
echo "<td><img src='" . htmlspecialchars($row["Reference-to-S3"]) . "' /></td>\n";
```